# How to use custom fields of category in static blocks, magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, category, static-block, custom-field

I want to add a custom attribute for category, then use that custom attribute value  in a static block and call that static block in a phml file of custom theme file.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Can you please explain what you are trying to achive

Comment: @AmitBera clear now?